# Editing local XML file with Javascript from Browser

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xmldom

I'm brand new to Javascript and I'm currently making a site for school (currently local but will be put online by school).
So I have XML files and I have made multiple XSLT stylesheets to go with them. What I want to do is that when the user chooses an XSLT file, the XML File is loaded and the following line:
`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="filename.xsl"?>`
is added to the XML an then open the XML in a new page (that way the browser will make the transformation automatically).

I have looked here and there, tried the XMLHttpRequest object but for some reason it doesnt seem to do anything in my script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please, post a significant subset of your XML file and of your XSL file. With the information you provided above, nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Or try to implement the short example Hello world! from http://www.herongyang.com/XML/XSL-First-Example-Hello-World.html